# Todo algoritmo deve ser finito?

Tags: algoritmo, terminologia

Todo algoritmo deve sempre terminar após um número finito de passos?

Parece trivial mas pergunto porque isso gerou outra dúvida que pode ser exposta no exemplo seguinte:

```
enquanto (VERDADE){
         ouvir_ligações_porta_8080
    }
```

O exemplo anterior é um algoritmo ou não?

Comment: Pode colocar um citação mais completa?

Comment: Vou fazer melhor, vou expandir a questão e tirar a referência ao livro, que achas @bigown?

Comment: Sei lá, este é um caso que me parece ser só uma questão de interpretação. O que não tem nada de errado nisso.

Comment: @Cold A citação seria essa? Finiteness: An algorithm must always terminate after a finite number of steps. Algorithm e satisfies this condition, because after step E1 the value of r is less than n;  so if r != 0, the value of n decreaes the next time step E1 is encountered. A decreasing sequence of positive intergers must eventually terminate, so step E1 is executed only a finite number of times for any given original values of n. Note, however, that the number of steps can become arbitrarily large; certain huge choices of m and n will cause step E1 to be executed more than milions times.

Comment: @Randrade, já não é necessário. E o memso livro de alguma forma responde a esta questão, mas queria sempre ouvir outras opiniões.

Comment: `Todo algorítimo deve sempre terminar após um número finito de passos?` a resposta é não para sistema em tempo real onde determinadas funções tendem ao infinito, manter uma porta em listen, manter um microfone capturando áudio, congelar um frame infinitamente (pausar o seu blue ray) ... o assunto é perturbador pois nada na vida é infinito huahuahua, presume-se que em algum momento sua função vai parar.

Comment: @bigown a citação do Randrade dá pra ver e avaliar se de facto é uma questão de interpretação :D

Comment: No algoritmo citado é comum o VERDADE ser uma variável e este processo que tende a ser finito enquanto VERDADE for verdadeiro. Em algum outro momento, outro processo pode notificar o precesso que esculta ligacoes na porta 8080 setando o valor de VERDADE como falso, fazendo com que na próxima iteração a VERDADE tenha valor falso e não escultando mais ligações na porta 8080.

Comment: @wryel, não é necessáriamente uma variável. Considere um true puro.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A melhor consideração a se fazer é que o seu exemplo é um método computacional, mas não um algoritmo. Vou defender o porquê desta afirmação em seguida.

Como:

- Quase todos os grandes artigos que contribuíram para a definição da palavra algoritmo estão em inglês.
- E a maioria dos livros de computação em português que utilizam a palavra algoritmo se baseiam em referências em inglês.

Vamos considerar que o significado da palavra algoritmo é o mesmo do equivalente em inglês *algorithm*. Assim podemos procurar pela definição de fontes confiáveis e com peso nos meios da matemática e da computação.

Definição pelo dicionário de Cambrige:

> A set of ​mathematical ​instructions that must be ​followed in a ​fixed ​order, and that, ​especially if given to a ​computer, will ​help to ​calculate an ​answer to a ​mathematical ​problem.
>
> Conjunto de instruções matemáticas que devem ser seguidos em uma ordem fixa, e que, especialmente se for dado a um computador, vai ajudar a calcular uma resposta para um problema matemático.

Definição pelo dicionário de Oxford:

> Math. and Computing. A procedure or set of rules used in calculation and problem-solving. A precisely defined set of mathematical or logical operations for the performance of a particular task.
>
> Matemática. e Computação. Um procedimento ou conjunto de regras utilizadas no cálculo e resolução de problemas. Um conjunto bem definido de operações matemáticas ou lógicas para a realização de uma determinada tarefa.

Definição no Wolfram MathWorld:

> An algorithm is a specific set of instructions for carrying out a procedure or solving a problem, usually with the requirement that the procedure terminate at some point.
>
> Um algoritmo é um conjunto específico de instruções para a realização de um procedimento ou para resolver um problema, geralmente com a exigência de que o procedimento termina em algum ponto.

Nenhuma das três definições explicita rigososamente que um algoritmo deve terminar.

A definição clássica de algoritmo é a de um procedimento sequencial e que termina em algum ponto. Porém novos tipos de algoritmos surgiram, como por exemplo os algoritmos paralelos, interativos, distribuídos, analógicos e quânticos que não encaixam bem na definição clássica. Deste modo, o conceito de algoritmo ainda está em processo de desenvolvimento e não é rigorosamente definido.

Mas na prática, dificilmente um programa que não termina será dito como um algoritmo. Um algoritmo deve resolver um problema e, portanto, usualmente retornará um valor que representa a solução. Se em algum ponto, a solução já foi calculada, por que o algoritmo deveria continuar? E se a solução não for calculada nunca, o algoritmo não possui sentido prático. O conceito de algoritmo que não termina é mais para questões teóricas do que práticas.

Portanto `ouvir_ligações_porta_8080` é um algoritmo, pois soluciona um problema.
Já `enquanto(VERDADE)` é um método computacional que chama um algoritmo várias vezes, mas ele nunca dá uma resposta final para o seu problema, então seria melhor não chamá-lo de algoritmo.

Comment: Abordagem interessante!

Answer (score 16):

Isto é um algoritmo, claro. E o algoritmo não precisa necessariamente ser finito. É desejável, mas não obrigatório. Quando isto ocorre é chamado de método computacional, conforme consta no livro [The Art of Computer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming), onde é definido que uma das características do algoritmo é a finitude. Há uma exceção para este caso já que há situações onde espera-se que apenas uma intervenção externa ao algoritmo o termine. Este caso é chamado de processo reativo (também retirado do mesmo livro).

De acordo com os comentários concluímos que o termo mais correto é que ele é um método computacional e não um algoritmo. Pelo menos formalmente falando. Não que alguém terá entendimento errado de chamar isto de algoritmo. Ao que tudo indica, academicamente o ramo da computação considera como condição essencial para chamar algo de algoritmo, entre outras características, que ele seja finito.

Se deseja usar os termos academicamente é melhor dizer que tem ali um método computacional. Se quer expressar algo que todos entendem, pode chamar de algoritmo à vontade, ninguém vai brigar com você, todos entenderão e isto é que importa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ok, mas o autor do mesmo livro diz que um Algorítimo deve (o termo usado mesmo é "must"), então a idéia é tentar perceber se deve e porquê não deve e o contrário com os devidos porquês.

Comment: Leia o que está entre parenteses no mesmo item do livro. Este "deve" é para atender esta característica, não para ser um algoritmo.

Comment: Começo a ver que é mesmo uma questão de interpretação. Eu não fico/fiquei com a mesma ideia, e olhando para esta sentença "A PROCEDURE that as all of the characteritics of an algorithm except taht it possibly lacks on finiteness MAY BE CALLED a COMPUTATIONAL METHOD", ou seja, eu entendo que procedimentos como o do meu exemplo é um método computacional e não necessáriamente um algorítimo.

Comment: Aí até pode ser. Mas fica a dúvida, algoritmo e método computacional são antagônicos ou o segundo é um tipo do primeiro? Não que eu ache que tenha muita relevância prática. Mas é um curiosidade interessante.

Comment: Antagónicos não diria, mas a relação de hereditariedade entre eles não sei. Parece-me que um algoritmo pode ser um método computacional mais não que todos métodos computacionais são algoritmos. E por outra, eu posso ter algoritmos que não são traduzidos necessariamente em métodos computacionais.

Answer (score 3):

Depende do contexto em que você estiver falando. Do ponto de vista do seu livro, exigir que os algoritmos sempre terminam vai simplificar muita coisa. Por exemplo, é mais fácil discutir sobre tempo de execução e complexidade computacional quando os programas terminam de rodar. Como você definiria o tempo de execução e a complexidade computacional de um programa de computador que roda pra sempre, manipulando um fluxo infinito de dados? :)

Comment: Se o fluxo de dados é infinito, logo haverá sempre uma rotina ou procedimento a ser executado, embora a complexidade pode ser determinada a priori e creio que a análise não deve ser feita desta forma. Imagine que certo procedimento seja O(log(n)), se o fluxo de dados é infinito logo correrá infinitamente. Ainda que seja O(1) se o fluxo for infinito, teremos O(1) infinitas vezes...

Comment: Creio que existe uma definição exata sobre o que estamos abordando aqui, e não creio que haja uma variância contextual.

Comment: A matemática é feita de definições exatas mas as definições sempre dependem do contexto :) Quanto ao seu comentário, acho que você está se embolando um pouquinho com o infinito. Antes de assumir que um procedimento é O(log(n)) é preciso definir o que significa a complexidade computacional de um algoritmo de entrada infinita (que foi a pergunta retórica que eu deixei). Também não faz muito sentido falar "O(1) infinitas vezes"...

Comment: A pergunta retórica apresentada é que leva a possibilidade de O(1) infinitas vezes... Mas para não dar muita volta, podias apresentar um outro contexto em que algoritmo tenha uma definição distinta (dá uma olhada no livro referenciado e vê o estudo sobre a etimologia até a aplicação do termo, poderá clarear)???

Comment: Dê uma olhada na página https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm_characterizations. Tem dezenas de definições que você pode escolher, dependendo do seu enfoque... Em particular algumas das definições vão um pouco na direção de que qualquer conjunto de instruções para uma máquina de Turing contaria como algoritmo (mesmo se a máquina de Turing não parar para algumas entradas). Quanto à parte do O(1) infinitas vezes, tente então escrever uma definição formal de o que isso significa :)

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada sim :). Imagine que tenhas um método para imprimir um nome na tela e o tempo de execução seja O(1). Agora imagine que usemos um "fluxo infinito de dados", ou seja (pelo que entendi) uma "lista infinita" de nomes, logo este método será executado infinitas vezes...

Answer (score 0):

Creio que todo algoritmo é finito sim, já que mesmo em situação que o programa execute infinitamente, algum erro ou o próprio sistema operacional pode ocasionar uma parada. A diferença é que nem sempre o critério de parada é definido, mas sempre existe a possibilidade do sistema parar

Answer (score -2):

Creio que um processo que utilize de qualquer dado - que será traduzido algebricamente/matematicamente em algum momento - para realizar uma função ou resolver um problema pode ser considerado um algoritimo. Agora no contexto da problemática apresentada, há sim um algoritimo (pois precisa de um dado/informação para funcionar e está "linkado" em etapas lógicas). Mas a estrutura onde esse algoritimo se encontra se assemelha a um fluxograma ou a uma linguagem que o computador entenda - no caso, os presentes aqui disseram que era um processo computacional.